# close window's form qgis

Tags: python, forms, pyqt5, qgis

I'm making custom forms for qgis 3 using qt designer and some python code behind to make verification.

However, I have a problem for mapping button action OK and Cancel. I first disconnect the button then I connect them to an other function to validate data in the form.

However when I try to call the close function (to close the window's form) it only make the form disappear but the window is still there

[image]

Here is my code :

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QDialogButtonBox, QComboBox, QLabel, QPushButton
import psycopg2

myDialog = None
cbb_implant = None
Validat = 0


def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):

    bdd = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost")
    cursor = bdd.cursor()

    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog

    dialog.hideButtonBox()

    global cbb_implant
    cbb_implant = dialog.findChild(QComboBox, "cbb_implantation")
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM l_implantation_type')
    fetch = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(fetch)>0:
        for i in range(0,len(fetch)) :
            cbb_implant.addItem(fetch[i][1])
        cbb_implant.setCurrentIndex(7)

    ok_chem = dialog.findChild(QPushButton, "ok_chem")

    ok_chem.clicked.connect(validate)


def validate():
    global Validat

    if Validat == 0 : 
        print("HELLO")
        Validat = 1
    else :
        myDialog.save()
        myDialog.close()
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found out an other way to close the whole window.

I simply emulated escape key press (by using pyautogui module) and it do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
myDialog.parent().close()
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

nameField = None
myDialog = None

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog
    global nameField
    nameField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"Name")
    buttonBox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox,"buttonBox")

    # Disconnect the signal that QGIS has wired up for the dialog to the button box.
    buttonBox.accepted.disconnect(myDialog.accept)

    # Wire up our own signals.
    buttonBox.accepted.connect(validate)
    buttonBox.rejected.connect(myDialog.reject)

def validate():
  # Make sure that the name field isn't empty.
    if not nameField.text().length() > 0:
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText("Name field can not be null.")
        msgBox.exec_()
    else:
        # Return the form as accpeted to QGIS.
        myDialog.accept()
```